# WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback gets called multiple times while using setState

Tags: flutter, dart

For some reason whenever I use setState((){}); in the function I pass in WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(), that function gets called multiple times.

Is there any way to overcome it?

Note: Both the code within and outside the setState get called.

Comment: Edit question and share your code please

Comment: It happened because I had called `setState((){})` within the callback passed to `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`. So the widget re-built itself after every (successful) build.

Comment: @NephewofStackoverflow I have the same problem like yours, had you found any solution?

Comment: Yes, It was because setState was being called within the callback.

Comment: Don't use WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback and setState within the build method.

Answer (score 5):

You can call setState after rendering is done by adding a post frame callback with [addPostFrameCallback](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html) method. This will be called only once and after build process is done.

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => setState(() {}));
```

Comment: Can this be used at any app stage or only initState?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but on my hand, the solution by @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 wasn't working, unfortunately (still called several time).

Only way for me was to create an async function and call it before building the rest, it will be executed after build:

```
//Works perfect for me
  Future<void> _asyncFunctionAfterBuild() async {
    setState(() {
      print("check if i'm printed several times!");
    });
 }

[...]

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _asyncFunctionAfterBuild();
    return Text("Blabla");
  }
```